# Как импортировать модуль в kv файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
KV = '''
#: import re
'''



raise ParserException(self, ln, 'Invalid import syntax')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 2:
           1:
     >>    2:#:import re
           3:Screen:
           4:    NavigationLayout:

 ...
 Invalid import syntax
```

Как правильно импортировать модуль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел [примеры импорта](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#special-syntax):

```
#:import name x.y.z
#:import isdir os.path.isdir
#:import np numpy
```

Попробуйте так (убрал пробел после двоеточия и пустую первую строку):

```
KV = '''\
#:import re
'''
```

Comment: Не помогло( Добавил полную ошибку

Comment: @MiDem, мб ему не нравится первая пустая строка? Обновил ответ